# I want Regular Expression For this Format(Years/M or Days/F) for ex:24Years/M or 24Days/F

Tags: javascript, regex

Any one please help me.

the user enter age in textbox but the age format should be Years/M or Years/F or Days/M or Days/F

Answer (score 1):

First number between 1 to 9, Optionally more numbers between 0-9, then years or days, then slash, then gender.

`^[1-9](?:[0-9]*)(?:Years|Days)\/(?:M|F)$`